# Expectation value of Wilson loop in Chern-Simons theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, topology, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory, wilson-loop

I have read Witten's paper, and I am interested on computing the expectation value of a Wilson loop with a representation $R$ on Chern-Simons theory in $d=3$. I am especially interested in cases for $G=SU(N)$, and spaces of the form $\Sigma \times S^1$. I understand, from section 4, that the way to go would be to start with the result for say $S^2 \times S^1$, and perform surgery to get the space $\Sigma \times S^1$. However, I can't find a concrete resource in which surgeries to $\Sigma = S^1 \times S^1$ or to $\Sigma=R^2$ are performed.

What would be the way to proceed here?

Alternatively, is there a different way to arrive at my objective? As far as I understand, canonical quantization will not work for $S^1 \times S^1 \times S^1$ or $R^2 \times S^1$, since they require $\Sigma \times R^1$ instead.